# Read RSSI bluetooth value from paired device on API15 (no GATT available)

Tags: android, bluetooth, rssi

I have created a bluetooth car that is controlled using a Galaxy Tab, from which I want to be able to frequentely (1-10 times per second) read the RSSI value to be able to always stay in range of the bluetooth, and if not the car is supposted to return to the last known place where the connection was within range.

My problem however, is that I am not able to read the RSSI value when paired to the bluetooth module in my car. Reading while discovering is not a problem, but does not help me in this case.

I have been looking around but can't find an answer how to make this possible using the API I am, which is 15, and therefore GATT is out of the question. Help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers :)